# jquery: how to write single click event for 2 or more different buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click

```
 $("#loggedinNav").click(function (e) {
     // do something
    });
```

this is my and i want to use same click functionality for other buttons, so can I achieve this behaviour like in this manner:

```
$("#loggedinNav" || "#mainlogo").click(function (e) {
     // do something
    });
```

where `||` = `or`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#loggedinNav, #mainlogo").click(function (e) { // do something });
```

Comment: I would do this, but if you go beyond two or three buttons you might want to consider creating a class that's assigned to the buttons, then use the class name instead of the ids.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to metaforce's answer.

You could do this:

```
var clickHandler = function(e) { 
    //Do stuff 

    };

$("#loggedinNav").click(clickHandler);
$("#mainlogo").click(clickHandler);
```

This would be better if you have a lot of buttons that need the handler or you want to do it in multiple functions.

Comment: yup, it's the same solution, but if your click handler is performing same actions, then it is better to do the same way as suggested earlier ... this'll save time when you want to modify your the action in future ...

Answer (score 1):

you can do `$("#loggedinNav,#mainlogo").click(...)` as per [JQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: not working, you have to put everything with same double qoutes ... as metioned by metaforce (see above solution)